# Using Cordova native Facebook plugin for Ionic app and DRF server with python-social-auth

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework, django-rest-framework, cordova-plugins, python-social-auth

At the moment, I'm using Cordova native FB plugin to log user in for my Ionic app. After this I want to authenticate and register the user with my DRF server and I plan to do this with python-social-auth.

But I soon realize a problem, the native FB plugin will return me the access token for FB directly and not the Oauth code, while python-social-auth use the Oauth code to authenticate user.

So I'm stuck with a choice: either pass the access token directly to my server (might not be a good practice) or try to figure some way else to get the Oauth code instead (which seems to be not possible with Cordova native plugin) and sacrifice ease of implementation and ease of use on my Ionic app. Can anyone suggest me a good way to solve this or which direction should I take?

Comment: Passing a token from client to server back-end is not a bad practice per se. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#confirm

Comment: Then with the access token, how do i validate it on my django server? Cause I look through python-social-app documentation and I can't find the relevant part for this anywhere as their pipeline starts with Oauth code.

Comment: Well you will have to modify _some_ part of this, if you want to go a different way than how those libraries/plugins usually work ...

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use_cases.html#signup-by-oauth-access-token

Comment: Thanks! It's a great help! But in the end I've managed to resolve the login with django-rest-auth.